# Resize a list of images in line command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, imagemagick

I would like to resize a list of images, all in the directory. To achieve that, I use `convert` from imagemagick. I would like to resize

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
...
```

into

```
image1-resized.jpg
image2-resized.jpg
...
```

I was wondering if there is a method to achieve this in a single command line. An elegant solution could be often useful, not only in this case.

EDIT:

I would like a **non** *script-like* solution, ie. without for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ls *.jpg|sed -e 's/\..*//'|xargs -I X convert X.jpg whatever-options X-resized.jpg
```

You can eliminate the sed and be extension-generic if you're willing to accept a slightly different final filename, 'resized-image1.jpg' instead of 'image1-resized.jpg':

```
ls|xargs -I X convert X whatever-options resized-X
```

Comment: Right! That's what I want! Without the sed pipe would be perfect, no matter if resize is in the beginning

Answer (score 10):

If you want to resize them to 800x600:

```
for file in *.jpg; do convert -resize 800x600 -- "$file" "${file%%.jpg}-resized.jpg"; done
```

(works in bash)

Answer (score 6):

[GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is even easier than for loops, and it's often faster:

```
parallel convert -resize 800x600 -- "{}" "{.}-resized.jpg" ::: *.jpg
```

A few things going on here, from right to left:

- `::: *.jpg` means run the command for every jpg file
- `{.}` means insert the current filename without the suffix (`.jpg`)
- `{}` means insert the current filename
- `parallel` means run the following command many times in parallel.  It will choose the max to do in parallel to match the number of cores your computer has.  As each one finishes it will launch the next one until all the jpg files are converted.

This runs the command `convert --resize 800x600 -- foo.jpg foo-resized.jpg` for each file.  The `--` tells convert to stop processing flags, in case a file name happens to start with a `-`.

P.S. On my mac I have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, so I was able to install parallel and convert with

```
brew install parallel
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: Nice answer - this is the way to go. Not sure what the `- -` part is though.

Answer (score 2):

If your image files have different extensions:

```
for f in *; do convert -resize 800x600 -- "$f" "${f%.*}-resized.${f##*.}"; done
```